# Visual Studio Code Source Control not in sync with Explorer

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

## Simple Version

I am using Visual Studio Code *(v.1.46.1)* on my dev machine to edit files in a GIT *(v.2.27.0)* Repo.
However, when I change a file and save it, it does not show up on the Source Control tab until I do a refresh.
Additionally, if I Discard changes on the Source Control tab, the file in the Editor does not update.
***NOTE**: I have seen several questions like this, but none of them have an answer that works for me.*

---

## Gory Details

#### What I tried

***FYI**:I also had Visual Studio Community 2019 and Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 releases from May 2020 installed.*

I uninstalled Visual Studio Code, both Visual Studios, and GIT.
I then deleted my Repo folders, deleted the .vs* and .git* folders under my \Users\ folder.
After that I re-installed GIT, then Visual Studio Code. *(But not Visual Studio Enterprise or Visual Studio Community)*

I still had the same issue.

#### Research

So, I created a VM, and installed GIT and Visual Studio Code. Everything works as expected there, so it isn't just a version issue.

**After some investigation...**

1. OUTPUT window for GIT when I save a file:

   - **VM**:

     ```
     > git status -z -u
     > git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
     > git rev-parse master
     > git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
     > git rev-list --left-right master...refs/remotes/origin/master
     > git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
     > git remote --verbose
     ...
     > git config --get commit.template
     ```
   - **Dev Box**: No output
2. OUTPUT window for GIT when I click on Open Changes:

   - **VM**:

     ```
     git.getSCMResource.uri file:///r%3A/MyProject/Scripts/Do-MyStuff.ps1
     repo root r:\MyProject
     > git show HEAD:Scripts/Do-MyStuff.ps1
     > git ls-tree -l HEAD -- R:\MyProject\Scripts\Do-MyStuff.ps1
     > git log --format=%H%n%aN%n%aE%n%at%n%ct%n%P%n%B -z -n21 -- r:\MyProject\Scripts\Do-MyStuff.ps1
     ```
   - **Dev Box**:

     ```
     git.getSCMResource.uri file:///r%3A/MyProject/Scripts/Do-MyStuff.ps1
     repo root r:\MyProject
     ```
3. When I Discard changes, the file in the open Editor:

   - **VM**: Automatically refreshes
   - **Dev Box**: Does not refresh
4. Modify a file open in Visual Studio Code editor, using Notepad

   - **VM**: Automatically refreshes when I return to Visual Studio Code
   - **Dev Box**: Does not refresh

---

## Question

What could make it so that Visual Studio Code doesn't detect *(or get notified?)* when a file is changed, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, and I figured out it was caused by a workaround needed to get git-lfs working with windows' built-in openssh (the details are [here](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3779#issuecomment-832728742) if you're interested).

The workaround caused git to hang on any ssh errors, and when that happened during vscode's autofetch, vscode would no longer automatically recognize any git-related changes (file modification, branch switching, etc.), but it WOULD work if I manually refreshed it.

Killing the spawned "git fetch" process returns vscode to normal, and git changes are recognized until another process hangs due to the workaround.

Hopefully this helps!